# Issue with JPopupMenu in a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jpopupmenu

I have this issue. In a custom JTree I implemented a JPopupMenu to display different JMenuItem according to the node selected using a MouseListener.
The JPopupMenu is shown when the mouse right button is clicked. The problem is that if I don’t choose an Item from the PopupMenu but instead I select another node in the tree, either with right or left buttons, this event is never caught by the tree MouseListener
Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this? In case an example is available I’ll appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: can't reproduce (with jdk6u27): the mouseEvents reach the listener installed on the tree, independent of whether the popup is visible or not. So could have been a bug in core now fixed, or a bug in the code you didn't show :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest maybe using a TreeSelectionListener for determining changes in selected node as opposed to the MouseListener and repopulating the JPopupMenu at that point, but that's your choice.

Trying to emulate your example, I was wondering, which methods did you override in your mouse listener?  In this simple example, the listener seems to get the events regardless of if the popup menu is showing or not.

EDIT - see my comment below, but the right click not selecting a node is default behavior.  This example will select the closest node to where the right click was made if possible.

```
public class SampleTree extends JFrame {
    private JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("Popup");

    public SampleTree() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Tree");
        final JTree tree = new JTree();

        tree.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
           public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    TreePath tp = tree.getClosestPathForLocation(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    if (tp != null) {
                        System.out.println(tp);
                        tree.setSelectionPath(tp);
                    }
                    menu.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });

        String letters = "ABCDEF";

        for (final char letter : letters.toCharArray()) {
            JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(letter));
            item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SampleTree.this, "You chose the letter: " + letter);
                }
            });
            menu.add(item);
        }

        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SampleTree st = new SampleTree();
                st.setSize(200, 200);
                st.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                st.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying
To your suggestion I can tell that I started evaluating TreeSelectionListener but TreeSelectionEvent does not have a way to determine which mouse button was pressed.
Regarding your example is quite similar to mine we both override the MouseReleased and MousePressed methods, although in your case the left button behaves as expected the right button still does as I described, the MousePressed and MousseClicked do not receives the event if the popupMenu is still visible.
If you find a solution please post it
Regards

Comment: I believe that's the default behavior for the JTree now based on this bug report: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4196497.  I altered my example to demonstrate how you could do this programmatically by selecting the node on a right mouse click.